# How do I authorize an User in AD Group in Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to authorize an USER against an AD group through Microsft Graph. Only members of the AD group can access the API. Which Microsoft Graph query (API URL) is required to do this authorization? Or are there any other options available?

Appreciate if you suggest BEST PRACTICES for this as well.

Thanks in advance for your suggestion and help.

Best Regards,
Deb

Answer (score 0):

If the API is using ASP.NET you can use the built-in OpenID connect functionality and use regular `[Authorize]` attributes on those API controllers or methods that you want to protect.

There is a [comprehensive sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims).

The sample uses regular OpenID Connect auth, and uses the JWT token claims to retrieve the user's group membership. In case the groups cannot be contained in the JWT token, the token will contains a link to where you can retrieve them. This is handled in the sample's [ClaimHelper.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/blob/master/WebApp-GroupClaims-DotNet/Utils/ClaimHelper.cs) file.

To get group claims in the JWT token, remember to follow [step 3](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims#step-3-configure-your-application-to-receive-group-claims) in the sample's setup procedures, since they are not there by default.

You can even put the group object IDs from AAD into the ASP.NET "Roles", so you can use the `[Authorize]` attribute like `[Authorize(Roles="217ea9e4-0350-4a2d-b805-d71317fa0245")]` where the GUID is the objectID of the group whose membership is required.

To achieve the last part, you need to first add the group claims to the manifest (step 3 referenced above), and then add `TokenValidationParameters` to the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions` where you define which claim type will define the Roles (in Startup.Auth.cs):

```cs
  new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
  {
      // add this:
      TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
      {
          RoleClaimType = "groups"
      },
      // end added code
      ClientId = ConfigHelper.ClientId,
```

The latter is probably not best practice, since you need the group's objectID in the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am stuck in where do I mention RoleCliamType="group", did not found the code in StartUp.Auth.cs.

Comment: Sample StartUp.Auth.cs does not have RoleClaimType

Comment: I added the ``TokenValidationParameters`` property to ``OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`` in the snippet, so it is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have created two groups e.g. Group1 and Group2. API should be accessible to Group1 not Group2. For Group1, its working fine with ROLE attribute, but when any user for Group2 trying to access API, authentication operation is running for long time (more than 5 minute), does not return any status (HTTP status), tried with sample application. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If it works for one group, it should work for the other. Perhaps try and hook a proxy in between to see the communication. I recommend Fiddler (https://telerik.com/download/fiddler). Configuring your .NET app to use Fiddler: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureDotNETApp , Making Fiddler decrypt HTTPS traffic: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

Comment: Implemented Authorization in ASP.NET API. Now How Do I create the PAYLOAD so that I can test it from another APP (CONSOLE, ASP.NET).

Comment: I can not hardcode the Group Id key in authorize attribute [Authorize(Roles="217ea9e4-0350-4a2d-b805-d71317fa0245")]. Becuase this key is different for deifferent environment. Is that way to make it DYNAMIC?

Comment: It's probably possible, but off hand I don't know how. As I mentioned "The latter is probably not best practice, since you need the group's objectID". The "best practice" would be to use AAD Roles instead - these you can define yourself in your application and assign users or groups to those roles. The role names can be used in the ``Authorize`` attribute, so you can reuse them across environments.  There is a different sample (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims) that describes this setup.

Comment: Thanks. Omitted “ROLE” attributed and checking the user by querying GRAPH API whether USER present in that particular group. Hope it will works for USER authorization. 
For the above authorization, I don’t want to change API method signature from IHttpActionResult to async Task<IHttpActionResult>, otherwise it has big impact in the application. Is there way to get the user groups (from ClaimHelper.cs) / AuthenticationContext. AcquireTokenSilentAsync synchronously?  If API signature changed, need to update/change Test Automation.